# How to update function call in timer when variable changes?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, timer

I am calling the 'connect()' function once, in an initialiser of a different class. However, when the value is changed of the 'url' variable, the timer doesn't update the function, and keeps calling the self.receive() method with the old 'url'. I would kindly appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

```
func connect() {
       self.receive()
       /// set up a Timer that refreshes with self.frequency
       Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: self.frequency, repeats: true) { _ in
           self.receive()
       }
   }
   
   func receive() {
       logger.log("Updating information")
       
       guard let url = url else {
           logger.warning("WiFi connectivity is missing an URL, updating is not possible")
           return
       }
       
       let request = AF.request(url, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
       request.responseDecodable(of: VehicleInformation.self) { response in
           if let value = response.value {
               self.vehicleInfo = value
               NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.contextUpdate, object: nil, userInfo: nil)
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: what is `url`, is it a `@State var`, part of a published var of a `ObservableObject`? How do you update the `url`, is it on the main thread? Show enough relevant code to understand what you are doing. The best would be to show us `minimal reproducible example`, see info here:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: An issue is not in the provided code, needed more info.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Code:

```
class NetworkManager {
      static let share = NetworkManager()

      let netStatusObserver = NetStatusObserver()

      init () {
          netStatusObserver.connect()
      }
}

class NetStatusObserver {
var url = "1"

func connect() {
       self.receive()
       /// set up a Timer that refreshes with self.frequency
       Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
           self.receive()
       }
   }
   
   func receive() {
       print(url)
   }
}
```

and I called it on `viewDidLoad`

```
let networkManager = NetworkManager.share
DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
    networkManager.netStatusObserver.url = "2"
}
```

Actually, the prints will change to `2`.

So, I think your code maybe somewhere else wrong.